What is Roboflow doing for its "exposure augmentation"?
I was able to find a small blurb here that describes what Roboflows exposure augmentation does. I'll reproduce the text here for convenience:

Adjust the gamma exposure of an image to be brighter or darker.
Percent: Select the percent up to which an image will be randomly
brightened or darkened. Up to 100 percent bright (completely white) or
100 percent dark (completely black).

There are a few things about this description that confuse me:

Exposure is a quantity that I associate with the physical acquisition of the image--not the digital image itself.
Does gamma exposure just mean "gamma correction"?
If this is talking about gamma correction, then what does 100% correspond to? As far as I can tell, gamma has no maximum or minimum value.
Roboflow has a separate "brightness" augmentation, but they don't clarify how this differs (I suppose it would be self-evident if it were clear that this were a gamma correction).

In the end, I don't understand what it is they mean by exposure augmentation. Is it clear to anyone else what they mean by this?
